# Issue with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, templating

I made a PHP framework that has a built in TPL system. It fetches the ending of the url, and finds the file that has that string. So if the url is `http://website.com/tagHere` the Tpl system would look for the file called `tagHere.php`. Everything works fine with it, but I'm now trying to expand the framework to have a built-in backend panel. I've tried multiple ways, but it just refuses to work.

I decided to take a look at Wordpress' htaccess, since they do exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Here is how their htaccess works.

They check if the requested file name is a file. If it isn't a file, then they check if it is a folder. If it isn't a folder, they redirect to index.php. I want it to check if it's a file/folder, and if it isn't to remove the .php tag from the URL, so the TPL system can get the specified file and return it.

Here was my original .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1`
```

Here is Wordpress' original .htaccess file.

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</ifmodule>
```

Here was my attempt:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
</ifmodule>
```

When I try the above htaccess, it returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rule

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Will always match every URL because it says something like "if there is a character in the URL, then redirect".

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*?)$ admin.php?location=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Still returns a 404 error. Not sure why... But I'm sure it's the htaccess, not the PHP.

Comment: It's hard to help you without all your code. What URL are you trying and what should the result be?

Comment: I'm trying to access this ----> http://intactdev.nu/templating-tags
It should return a HTML web page.